# fullcalendar priority for overlapping event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar, overlap

I am trying to set a priority to an event which should overlaps first. Default fullcalendar overlaps the event which time-start is later. Lets say

I have two events:

Event 1 - time_start: 11:00 time_end: 11:05
Event 2 - time_start: 11:01 time_end: 20:00

Now fullcalendar would overlap Event 2 even its duration is longer than the first one - and thats the point. I want to say, that Event 2 has more priority than Event 1. If I would say Event 2 starts at the same time as Event 1 does, the display of those events would be correct (as I wish).

Example 1 on code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLvMrg?editors=0010
Example 2 (same time start) on code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaoYvE?editors=0010

Fullcalendar initialization (without event-data):

```
    $(function() { // document ready

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev, title, next, today',
                center: '',
                right: 'dailyView, weeklyView'            },
            nowIndicator: true,
            columnFormat: 'dddd',    // like 'Monday', for day views
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            allDayDefault: false,
            displayEventTime: false,
            events: [],
            views: {
                agenda: {
                    allDaySlot: false,
                    slotDuration: '00:05:00',
                    slotLabelInterval: 5,
                    slotLabelFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
                    slotEventOverlap: true,
                    titleFormat: 'DD. MMMM YYYY'
                }
            },
            height: function () {

                console.log(window.innerWidth + "x" + window.innerHeight);

                var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
                var heightRatio = 0.8;

                if (screenHeight >= 1200) {
                    heightRatio = 0.85;
                } else if (screenHeight >= 1080) {
                    heightRatio = 0.835;
                } else if (screenHeight >= 900 && screenHeight < 1080) {
                    heightRatio = 0.82;
                } else if (screenHeight >= 768 && screenHeight < 900) {
                    heightRatio = 0.77;
                } else if (screenHeight >= 590 && screenHeight < 900) {
                    heightRatio = 0.73;
                } else {
                    heightRatio = 0.68;
                }

                return $(window).height() * heightRatio;
            }
        });

});
```

Screenshots for example 1: [image: screenshot for example 1]

[image: screenshot for example 2]

Is there a way to prevent this? I tried playing around with the slotEventOverlap attribute and as well with the eventOverlap as function - but without success.

I would appreciate your help!

Regards,

Comment: if the events have the same start time and duration, you can use eventOrder to set an ordering rule (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/) but it doesn't apply if the start time or the durations are different, unfortunately. I'm not sure there is anything you can do about this, except submit a feature request, or alter the source code yourself.